# How to change update server of Windows 10 using registery?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, windows-update

I change update server address for local windows 7 using following registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\WUStatusServer
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\DisableWindowsUpdateAccess
```

Now i want to change them in windows 10. Changing these keys cause error 0x8024002e when trying updating! Every thing is OK because Windows updates properly when i use Group Policy Editor to change these parameters. Did  Microsoft change the registry location of these parameters?

Comment: Why not just use the GPO if you have the option to? Manually tweaking the registry is usually a bad idea for such important settings it could very well be that those keys change though I find it unlikely. What are you setting `DisableWindowsUpdateAccess` to?

Comment: I want to this using command line tools. I found there is no way to change GPO in windows cmd! The key `DisableWindowsUpdateAccess` prevent my client's Windows to get updates from Windows Official update servers.

Comment: @RezaGhodsi so presumably you're also precluding the use of PowerShell or generally anything else that's useful such as VBS?